# click on one component, toggle another component through Angular services

Tags: angular

I have two components with shared services.
So click on button in one component, change the boolean value from another component

shared.service.ts

```
 sharedService.toggle = false;
```

comp1.component.HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toggleme()">
```

comp1.component.ts

```
toggleme(){
this.sharedService.toggle = !this.sharedService.toggle
}
```

comp2.component.html

```
<div class="showHide" *ngIf="this.sharedService.toggle">
............
</div>
```

Comment: use get set to update toggle state in service.

Comment: but I am sending value from component, set and get in service will do that?

Comment: The reason why this is not working is beause no one is "telling" the component that the `.toggle ` value has changed. See the answer below how to solve

Comment: @JacopoSciampi thanks but I took toggleVal = true but onload, <div class="showhide"> is hidden, I want to show this div on load and onclick it should be hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subject/behaviorsubject for this.

**shared.service.ts**

```
private toggleState = new Subject();
public toggleState$ = this.toggleState.asObservable();
private toggleVal = false;

emitData(){
   this.toggleVal = !this.toggleVal;
   this.toggleState.next(this.toggleVal);
}
```

**comp1.component.ts**

```
toggleme(){
   this.sharedService.emitData();
}
```

**comp2.component.html**

```
<div class="showHide" *ngIf="this.sharedService.toggleState$ | async">
............
</div>
```

Comment: I took toggleVal = true but onload,  <div class="showhide"> is hidden, I want to show this div on load and onclick it should be  hidden

Comment: by default u set as false. in ngOnInit()  you can call this.sharedService.emitData(); which will set to true and DIV block will be shown.

Comment: so by default I took it as true, and then I called this.sharedService.emitData(); in ngOnInit() of comp2.component.ts but still onload that div is hidden

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkf5am?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts. Refer this

Comment: By default, can You show Hello Angular and on click hide it?

Comment: Updated stackblitz. You need to allow child component oninit to execute. added setTimeout delay.

Comment: When angular in runtime execute oninit method in parent=>child component. We have subscribe method in child component. without setTimeout, initial value will be lost. So we are sending data after initial time interval. upvote, so helpful to others.

Comment: I marked it as correct answer, I can't upvote it sorry, new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I used setTimeout on comp2.ts and also tried on comp1.ts. but still its hidden sorry